# why coalesce returns Scalar sub-query has returned multiple rows even though the values are distinct - SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, coalesce, trino

I have 2 tables that I want to join. These tables are `kp.pi` and `g.gu`

`kp.pi` joins with `g.gu` based on `pi.xx_id = gu.yy_id` and on `pi.xx_type = gu.yy_type`, and I want to get the `userid` field from `g.gu` table after this join.

However, in some cases, because the type (i.e. pi.xx_type = gu.yy_type) doesn't match in both tables, it will return null for `userid`. Hence, I want to exclude this join condition to get the `userid` from `g.gu` if the types doesn't match.

So the query will be the same, just excluding the `pi.xx_type = gu.yy_type` join condition to get userid from `g.gu`.

I tried to do this using coalesce but somehow keep getting the error:

`Scalar sub-query has returned multiple rows`
even though the `userid` values are distinct in the `g.gu` table.

Could anyone see whats wrong with my query below pls?:

```
  select submission_id, xx_id, coalesce (userid ,
                  (select distinct userid from 
                 ( SELECT *
                 from kp.pi
                 where source like '%abc%'
                 and id in (123,
                 456,
                 7877
                 )
                 ) pi

                  left join

                  (select  yy_id,
                        id as userid,
                         case
                         when type = 1 then 'bb'
                         when type = 2 then 'cc'
                         when type = 3 then 'dd' end as yy_type
                 from g.gu)
                 on xx_id = yy_id
                 )
                 )
                  as test_userid              
                 from
                 (select
                 id as submission_id,
                 xx_id,
                 xx_type
                 from kp.pi
                 where source like '%abc%'
                 and id in (123,
                 456,
                 7877
                 )
                 ) pi

                 left join

                 (select yy_id,
                  id as userid,
                  case
                         when type = 1 then 'bb'
                         when type = 2 then 'cc'
                         when type = 3 then 'dd' end as yy_type
                 from g.gu   
                 ) gu
                 on pi.xx_id = gu.yy_id
                and pi.xx_type = gu.yy_type
```

Comment: Please provide DDL statements to create the tables involved and statements to add a minimum amount of data to reproduce your issue.. Without this it is very hard to help. In principle though `SELECT DISTINCT ` does not guarantee that only one record is returned. Have you tried running these sub-queries individually to see how many different records are returned?

Comment: What is DDL statements? And yes, I did run the subquery and it returns unique userids!

Comment: **DDL** = Data Definition Language, this is a subset of SQL that creates tables and other objects. **DML** = Data Manipulation Language, another SQL subset that inserts and updates data. What we require is **sample data** for each table and ideally also supply the DDL for both tables.   See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Without sample of representative data assumptions about the data need to be made. I believe you are trying to give priority to the userid that has the matching `pi.xx_type = gu.yy_type` but if that isn't available to use userid where that condition isn't met. Instead of trying to place this logic into the join, I suggest using `row_number() over(partition by id order by case when type in (1,2,3) then 1 else 2 end)` this will give each `gu.id` a row number of 1, and due to the ordering used, that row number will be amongst the types 1,2,3 if available otherwise to the next available type. Then, by using this row number in the join condition you can only get 1 row per `gu.id` and that row will be prioritised by matching type/unmatched type.

```
SELECT
      pi.id AS submission_id
    , pi.xx_id
    , gu.userid AS test_userid
FROM kp.pi
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
          yy_id
        , id AS userid
        , CASE 
            WHEN type = 1 THEN 'bb'
            WHEN type = 2 THEN 'cc'
            WHEN type = 3 THEN 'dd'
            END AS yy_type
        , row_number() over(partition by id 
                            order by case when type in (1,2,3) then 1 else 2 end) as rn
    FROM g.gu
    ) gu ON pi.xx_id = gu.yy_id AND gu.rn = 1
WHERE pi.source LIKE '%abc%'
    AND pi.id IN (123, 456, 7877)
```

If this does not solve the problem (e.g. you do want types aa and bb and cc for each gu.id if available) then please provide sample data from each table to fully represent your issue.